# Can we skip fast if we aren't counting?

Tags: fasting

People usually does fasts in 2 ways. Either they do fasting till certain days like 11 or 16 or 51 days (depending on whose fast is this) ect.

And some does fast without counting days. These are prople who planning to carry fasts for very long period that's why they don't count.

Now question is, If one doing fasts (in coutless way) and got some proplems or issues and he planning to skip fast for that day for certain reason, can he do that?

I mean, If one don't want to quit(by doing udyapana) fasting but instead just want to skip fast for one day. He/she don't want to do fast for some reason e.g. Fealing weak or any other reason. Skipping fast one day will do any harm if our fasting is without counting and without any sakalpa towards Lord?

Comment: it's not clear what you're asking. do people fast (not eat anything) for 11 days, let alone 51 ??

Comment: @ram For example: Some do Lord Shiva's fast for 16 (days) Mondays. And some do fast of Lord shiva on Monday but they don't count how many Mondays they have done because they want to do Monday fasts for long period, that's why counting doesn't matter for them. My Q. was, If one is doing fast in countless manner (no fixed number of fasts like 16) then he can skip one fast in between or not?

Comment: doesn't it depend on the sankalpa of individual ? like before starting a religious fast, they are supposed to say sankalpa (intention) of 'today i'm going to fast', or 'for next  20 days days i'm going to', or 'for next 2 years' etc. ?

Comment: @ram This is what I have mentioned in last line of my question that if he hasn't done any sankalapa then he is free to skip? He/she wants to do fasts as long as he/she could without sakalpa, coz sakanlpa might break but if we do without sankalpa then there is no chance of getting sin.

Comment: it also depends on the phala / result the karta is expecting from the fast. if it is done with sva-prayojana (self-benefit) in mind, then most likely it has to be done WITH sankalpa (just like yagna, or else fruits can't be dealt out by devatas properly). if they are doing fast for bhagavad-prayojana (God's-pleasing or loka-kshema), then the need for explicit sankalpa can be overlooked, and the skipping can also be overlooked. but if they are doing 3-combo of without sankalpa, for self-benefit, and skipping - i don't know.. btw, why don't u mention the exact fast you are undertaking?

Comment: @ram _"why don't u mention the exact fast you are undertaking?"_  I didn't mention exact fast coz for some user it might appear like personal advice. User here do not hazitate even a bit to flag any post. I feel always scared a little while posting any question coz of unneccessaroy flagging here.

Comment: @Rishabh you're right. If you mentioned what fast you want, you might have been flagged as personal advice. In such cases, ask your question clearly and mention it clearly that you want a general answer. For example, I asked a question about what should we do when a scripture contradicts my morality. I asked this because I found a statement that was mind blowing immoral to me. So I included that statement and asked clearly about in general. When I did this, I got answers for both, in general and that specific line.

Comment: @Random-15, i know which question you are referring to that seems 'mind-blowingly' immoral to you - it's about child marriage. you are completely missing the point that it was only child marriage, it was not child sexual relations. marriage had a lofty goal - platonic attachment first before carnal desire entered mind. the bride would only be sent to husband's home after attaining menarche (periods), and consummation would only happen a couple years after that, which just so happens to be the marriageable age (16) accepted around world today.

Comment: @random-15 What are you talking about? I am not getting you last comment at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you have said in the Sankalpa before starting the fasts. In Hinduism, whether its Puja, Japa or Vrata, everything is preceded by a Sankalpa, where we state what we are doing on which particular days and what we expect in return of our efforts.

For e.g. for Maha Shivaratri vrata the following is a Sankalpa mantra:

> Om tat sat - adya phAlgune mAsi krishna pakshe chaturdashyAm tithau
>   (or trayadashyAm tithAvArabhya) amuka-gotrah (Gotra of the performer) shri-amukah (name of the performer)
>   shri-shiva-pritikAmah shivarAtri-vratam-aham karishye ||
>
> Today on this Phaluguna month's Krishna Chaturdashi Tithi, I, belonging
>   to such Gotra is doing the Shivaratri vrata for the desire of pleasing
>   Lord Shiva.
>
> **Anhika Kritya - 1st Khanda.**

Similarly, there will be corresponding Sankalpas for all sorts of scenarios.
One should complete the vrata as promised in the mantra. Not doing so will be an offence.

But, if no such Sankalpa mantra was recited before starting the fasts, then it does not matter whether you skip some fasts or not. Because there was no promise made. So, now it depends on your convenience and wish.